# Laravel incorrect stored datetime into database on jpbs and queues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

simply after creating data into database i see wrong datatime as `created_at` and `updated_at` into `phpMyAdmin`,

i set `Asia/tehran` in laravel `config/app` file and my system date time is correct and updated and when i logging `now()` with `carbon` i get this output:

```
Carbon @1532117471 {#1179 ▼
  date: 2018-07-21 00:41:11.142496 Asia/Tehran (+04:30)
}
```

and this is correct with my system datetime, on database datetime for `created_at` and `updated_at` is: `2018-07-20 19:58:26`

**THIS PROBLEM HAPPENS WHEN I USE LARAVEL JOB-QUEUE**

clock in this time is `00:41:11` not `19:58:26`, how can i resolve this problem and fix that?

Comment: actually it's correct to have date time in database that points to 0 GMT.  it's done for flexibility when You get data from db eloquent will adapt that time for Your timezone. try to get data from db using orm (eloquent)  and do dump of record You'll see that time is adapted to app's timezone

Comment: @num8er You think wrong i get wrong datetime with eloquent too

Comment: Laravel creates the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns as `timestamp` fields, not datetime. According to MySql, timestamps are stored in the database in UTC. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Comment: @JPark this problem happens when i use laravel job-queue

Comment: Are you running the queue with cron? Try running by the command `php artisan queue:listen` to see if that makes a difference. It may be a server misconfiguration if that's the case.

Comment: @JPark i use `php artisan schedule:run` and `php artisan queue:work` commands and i have only problem in jobs and queues, i'm wondering why laravel don't use timezone settings from `app.php`

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why Laravel wouldn't be using the configuration when running the queue, unless something is overwriting that timezone value somewhere. If you recently changed the settings in your `app.php`, you could try clearing the cache `php artisan config:clear` and restarting the queue `php artisan queue:restart` to see if that helps.

Comment: @DolDurma ok. I'm wrong, You're genius, go fix Your problem  https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14428

Comment: Just Google it: `laravel console run does not use timezone`

Comment: What is the timezone used on the server where your database is? If the timezone is different from the one you set it might be what causes this inconsistency. Have you checked this?

Comment: @JPark clearing configs solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You're looking into created_at and updated_at of laravel. They are being used as timestamps of when it was created based of your larave's `config/app` timezone.
How can you change this?

Option 1. Go to `config/app.php` and change timezone to your desired one.

Option 2. Manage a model's created at with mutators.

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator

On your Eloquent Model, you simply create:

```
public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value) {
  /*
  $value is the value it is going to initially be stored
  This date format is required due to mySql's timestamp restriction.
  However, you can create a date with Carbon, and as long as you format into that 
  structure Y-d-m H:i:s it will do just fine
  */
  $this->attributes['created_at'] = Date("Y-m-d H:i:s);
}
```

Note: In order to trigger this function, you're required to use Eloquent's Create, as in:

```
$data = ['some_field' => 'hi',
         'some_ther_field' => 'hiSomeOtherField'];
SomeModel::create($data);
```